# Arguments inside string in shell script

Tags: string, shell, curl, arguments

I'm trying to use a shell script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "First arg: $1"
echo "Second arg: $2"
curl -w "\n" -d '{"ssid": "$1", "psk": "$2" }' \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -X POST localhost:8080/connect
```

The problem is that inside the curl command it takes $1 and $2 as strings and not arguments. If i try to remove the ":s then it doesn't work at all.

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use double quotes (to get variables expanded correctly) but *escape* the qoutes within the string with backslashes in front of them (and drop `-X POST` when you use `-d`, [because](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/09/11/unnecessary-use-of-curl-x/)):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "First arg: $1"
echo "Second arg: $2"
curl -w "\n" -d "{\"ssid\": \"$1\", \"psk\": \"$2\" }" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8080/connect
```